Jumping to function definition for third party libraries for .net using nvim-lspconfig?
I installed nvim-lspconfig with csharp_ls so in my project I can jump to function definition no problem. When it comes jumping to system or third party code (like for example     Console.WriteLine("...")) it gives me an error:
/usr/local/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/util.lua:1801: index out of range
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function '_str_byteindex_enc'
    /usr/local/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/util.lua:1801: in function 'locations_to_items'
    ...nvim/lazy/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/__lsp.lua:197: in function 'handler'
    /usr/local/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/client.lua:687: in function ''
    vim/_editor.lua: in function <vim/_editor.lua:0>

Is it a bug or a feature?
Is it something that I miss from my config or it's the expected behavior?

It looks to me like a bug.

I suspect either the LSP client in Neovim or or the server; I would consider reporting to both.
